# How do I check if a textinput in a form includes just a number and a certain prefix?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my form to only accept inputs like:

BS-142

bs-213421

Bs-111111

meaning just this prefix and a number or just the number

This is what my current try looks like:

```
function validateForm(){
    var tag = document.forms["add"]["tag"].value;
    if (isNaN(tag) || tag != "BS-") {
        alert('FALSCHE FORMATIERUNG!'); window.location='index.php';
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the PHP to support a PHP tag in this question

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the pattern attribute of your input element (reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) or check the String using JavaScript's `String.match()` method (reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp).

Although I highly recommend also checking on your server-side as client-side validation is not very secure.